# AmCharts hovering shows div name

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, amcharts

Whem I'm hovering on the chart, the `div-id` where the chart was drawn shows up (CATEGORY in this example). Is there anyway to hide this?

[image: Div Name showing in AmCharts]

Comment: Is that blue line a chart cursor or a guide? Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: The blue line is a chart cursor.

Comment: Post a fiddle that reproduces this. The AmCharts library doesn't display a random "CATEGORY" on hover, so it's likely an issue with your overall code.